# Can data keys for enter, update,exit in d3js be a list?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make the tree from 
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

The key in this tree is just the id, which is just an integer.

I want to specify a key such that along with the id of the node, I also have an extra variable such that when I toggle that variable, my circle gets selected in the update section.

I tried passing a list like

```
data(data, function () {
   return [(d.id || d.id = ++i), d.value];
})
```

I want it to get updated when I change my d.value to something else.
So far, I haven't had any luck with it, plus I can't seem to find it in the documentation. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for `.data()` is a function. This function tells D3 how to match data in the first argument to the data bound to existing elements. That is, if the key function returns the same value for an element in the first argument to `.data()` and the data bound to an existing DOM element, the DOM element is assumed to represent that data.

If the data element is matched, it will be in the update selection. If it is not matched, it will be in the enter selection. All existing DOM elements that are not matched by data will be in the exit selection.

So in your case, you don't actually need to change anything because the node will be part of the update selection.

Comment: ah, ok. I logged it and saw it indeed does come in the update section. I think is problem is that I'm keeping a copy of the node data somewhere in the data field of some other tag, and updating that  won't affect my original. I originally thought it was a reference, but I think jquery makes a copy when I do `$(tag).data(data)` . Can I ask you whether you know how I could pass a reference in there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reference and JQuery wouldn't make a copy like that. Do you mean that you bind the data to different DOM elements and then update a subset of the DOM elements?

Comment: yes, I have a json which I use to make the tree. Then I save the data for a particular node in the a html tag using the data attribute. Then I change the data in the html tag (not the json). I want this to come in the update selection, should it happen by design or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "save the data for a particular node in a HTML tag" or how you would then change that. Can you post your code please?

Comment: By save the data I mean, I added an event listener in `on.("mouseover", function(d) { $("#someid).data(d);})` . And then on click on #someid I do , `var data = $("#someid").data(); data.value = null;` . Now I want this change reflected in my update section, which is not happening

Comment: Thanks Lars, I figured it out. I was recomputing the nodes in the tree from the original JSON.